# df.describe() Type suddenly changed Values missing now

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used `df.describe()` to get mean, 25% Quartile, 75% Quartile.
Everything worked perfectly as I wished with the numeric description.
Now I deleted some columns of the dataframe and suddenly it gives me a categorial description and so I can't use mean, 25%,... anymore.

Everything besides the number of columns (96 before, now 49) remained the same.

Can anyone explain why this happened?

The column names are W01,W02,...W96 where everything worked fine. (I got a numeric description). Now the names are W01,W02,...W49 and now I get a categorial description)

**BEFORE:**

```
df.describe()
                    W01
    count  1.010000e+02
    mean   1.088165e+06
    std    1.071501e+06
    min    0.000000e+00
    25%    3.186370e+05
    50%    1.195219e+06
    75%    1.475124e+06
    max    9.774923e+06
```

**AFTER:**

```
  df.describe()
            W01
    count   101
    unique  100
    top       0
    freq      2
```

In the end the logical Error appears, that the column "25%" cant be found but that's not my question.

What can I do to avoid the change of the description?

EDIT: both dataframes are created from a csv that is absolutly identical besides the one with 49 columns has less columns...

Comment: could it be that you accidentally changed the datatype of the remaining column? Can you share the deletion code?

Comment: I created the df by reading a csv, I just changed the csv and doublechecked that all entries are the same besides that there are column 50 to 96 deleted.

df = pd.read_csv('./Plausi_Set1.csv') 
which has 98 columns, but I drop two that I dont need.
AND
df = pd.read_csv('./Plausi_Set.csv')
which has 51 columns and I drop the same columns as before because I don't need them

Comment: use `df.astype(float)`. Tell me if it works!

Comment: You are a legend. it works

Comment: I'm glad it works!, I've published my solution in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert to float:

```
df.astype(float)
```